# SQL select statement PHP store dynamic multiline result into variable and convert into string for sending in an email

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables, select

I need to send a summary of a table select in an email.

```
/*
Table name: comments

username   comment             language      date
--------------------------------------------------------
Daniel     I am Daniel.        en            2019-05-01
Michael    I am Michael!       de            2019-05-04
Sean       I am Sean           en            2019-05-06
Sarah      I am Sarah.         it            2019-06-12

...and so on...
*/
```

These are basically comments from a conversation. I want to select only the ones with language=en and summarize them in a variable.

```
//db connection:
$conn = mysqli_connect("dbserver", "dbusername", "dbpassword", "dbname") or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
$conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}  

//selecting:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE language='en' ORDER BY date ASC";
$rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

How do I go from here to get the following variable for an email content?

```
$email_content = '
<b>Daniel</b> 2019-05-01<br>
I am Daniel.
<br><br>
<b>Sean</b> 2019-05-06<br>
I am Sean
';
```

...which should look in an html email like this:

**Daniel** 2019-05-01
I am Daniel.

**Sean** 2019-05-06
I am Sean

I know how to make an email transmission, so I only need the variable, filled with the select results and a bit formatted with html.

Comment: What exactly is giving you trouble?  Have you made any attempt to achieve what you want?

Comment: @PatrickQ Of course, several. It's solved though.

Answer (score 2):

try this solution

```
$email_content = '';
while($row = mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
{
    $email_content .= '<b>'.$row['username'].'</b> '.$row['date'].'<br> '.$row['comment'].'<br><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the results and assign variable.

```
$email_content  = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) {

       $email_content .= '
                <b>'.$row['username'].'</b>'.$row['date'].'<br>'.
                $row['comment'].'
                <br><br>';
    }
```

Comment: If you add a period before the equal (.=) yours will work and I am willing to upvote it too. I like your multi line appearance even better than the other one liners I upvoted (but they work).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result))
{
  $email_content .= '<b>'.$row['username'].'</b>'.$row['date'].'<br>'.$row['comment'].'<br><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I didn't do the exact HTML you provided though

```
$email_content  = "";
while ($row = $rs_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $email_content .= "<p>";
    $email_content .= "<b>" .  htmlspecialchars($row['username'])  ."</b>";
    $email_content .= "<span>" .  htmlspecialchars($row['date'])  ."</span>";
    $email_content .= "<p>" .  htmlspecialchars($row['comment'])  ."</p>";
    $email_content .= "</p>\n";
}
```

I have used [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to prevent HTML injection